# can amazon lambda be used to be observe firebase events in a long-running worker

Tags: firebase, aws-lambda

Is it possible to use amazon lambda to create a long running observer/monitor that keeps a socket open to firebase to watch for events?  Ideally there would be something that fires off events to lambda from firebase but I don't know of anything like that.

Is there any other way to put an adapter around firebase so that it can create discrete events that doesn't require a long running connection open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can not. `Amazon Lambda` is event-driven and made only for short-running processing, see `Timeouts` and `Memory limits` in [AWS Lambda official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

I suggest you look into integrating `Firebase` with `SNS` and then you can subscribe your `Lambda function` to the `SNS Topic` and have it process incoming events.

Comment: how would you integrate sns with firebase in a severless way?

Comment: That may not be possible. I'm not familiar with `Firebase` itself.